# Dataframe classification and sorting optimization problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to take the two letters in the dataframe column `'category'` and the maximum 4 in the other column `'data1'`, and sort them according to certain rules. I used the method of slicing and sorting according to the letters in the category, and then using `concat` to merge. The code is as follows. Is there an easier way than this?

```
import numpy as np
from time import time
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
n = 200
df['category'] = np.random.choice(('A', 'B'), n)
df['data1'] = np.random.randint(1, 10000, len(df))
df['data2'] = np.random.randint(1, 10000, len(df))
a = df[df['category'] == 'A'].sort_values(by='data1', ascending=False).head(4)
b = df[df['category'] == 'B'].sort_values(by='data1', ascending=False).head(4)
df = pd.concat([a, b]).sort_values(by=['category', 'data1'], ascending=[True, False]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

  category  data1  data2
0        A   9963   7174
1        A   9921   1787
2        A   9870   6105
3        A   9779   7189
4        B   9938   4259
5        B   9714   9362
6        B   9622   7033
7        B   9600   5718
```

I tried `lambda` again, the code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from time import time
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame()
n = 200
df['category'] = np.random.choice(('A', 'B'), n)
df['data1'] = np.random.randint(1, 10000, len(df))
df['data2'] = np.random.randint(1, 10000, len(df))
df = df.groupby('category').apply(lambda x: x[x['data1'].isin(x['data1'].nlargest(4))]).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.sort_values(by=['category', 'data1'], ascending=[True, False]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#for same random data for compare
np.random.seed(2021)


df = pd.DataFrame()
n = 200
df['category'] = np.random.choice(('A', 'B'), n)
df['data1'] = np.random.randint(1, 10000, len(df))
df['data2'] = np.random.randint(1, 10000, len(df))
a = df[df['category'] == 'A'].sort_values(by='data1', ascending=False).head(4)
b = df[df['category'] == 'B'].sort_values(by='data1', ascending=False).head(4)
df1 = pd.concat([a, b]).sort_values(by=['category', 'data1'], ascending=[True, False]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df1)
  category  data1  data2
0        A   9882   9868
1        A   9855   6701
2        A   9798   1058
3        A   9669   7334
4        B   9973   3668
5        B   9900   4340
6        B   9846   7885
7        B   9659   4933
```

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both columns first and then add [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df1 = (df.sort_values(by=['category', 'data1'], ascending=[True, False])
         .groupby('category')
         .head(4)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
  category  data1  data2
0        A   9882   9868
1        A   9855   6701
2        A   9798   1058
3        A   9669   7334
4        B   9973   3668
5        B   9900   4340
6        B   9846   7885
7        B   9659   4933
```

Comment: Your code is really concise, can you help me see another similar problem? [Dataframe classification and sorting optimization problem 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66811809/dataframe-classification-and-sorting-optimization-problem-2)