# Dataframe classification and sorting optimization problem 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I asked a sorting problem before, and someone solved it use `DataFrame.sort_values` by both columns first and then add `GroupBy.head`.

[Dataframe classification and sorting optimization problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66780162/dataframe-classification-and-sorting-optimization-problem)

Now I encounter a more complicated sorting. I need to classify the dataframe by `category`. Each `category` is filtered according to the value of `data1` when the value of `data2` of the class is the largest, and then sorted

The code is as follows, how to optimize it?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
n = 200
df['category'] = np.random.choice(('A', 'B'), n)
df['data1'] = np.random.rand(len(df))*100
df['data2'] = np.random.rand(len(df))*100

a = df[df['category'] == 'A']
c = a[a['data2'] == a.data2.max()].data1.max()
a = a[a['data1'] <= c]
a = a.sort_values(by='data1', ascending=False).head(4)

b = df[df['category'] == 'B']
c = b[b['data2'] == b.data2.max()].data1.max()
b = b[b['data1'] <= c]
b = b.sort_values(by='data1', ascending=False).head(4)

df = pd.concat([a, b]).sort_values(by=['category', 'data1'], ascending=[True, False]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

  category      data1      data2
0        A  28.194042  98.813271
1        A  26.635099  82.768130
2        A  24.345177  80.558532
3        A  24.222105  89.596726
4        B  60.883981  98.444699
5        B  49.934815  90.319787
6        B  10.751913  86.124271
7        B   4.029914  89.802120
```

I use groupby, I feel the code is too complicated, can it be optimized?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
n = 200
df['category'] = np.random.choice(('A', 'B'), n)
df['data1'] = np.random.rand(len(df))*100
df['data2'] = np.random.rand(len(df))*100

a = df[df['category'] == 'A']
c = a[a['data2'] == a.data2.max()].data1.max()
a = a[a['data1'] <= c]
a = a.sort_values(by='data1', ascending=False).head(4)

b = df[df['category'] == 'B']
c = b[b['data2'] == b.data2.max()].data1.max()
b = b[b['data1'] <= c]
b = b.sort_values(by='data1', ascending=False).head(4)

df2 = pd.concat([a, b]).sort_values(by=['category', 'data1'], ascending=[True, False]).reset_index(drop=True)
df3 = df.groupby('category').apply(lambda x: x[x['data1'].isin(x[x['data1'] <= x[x['data2'] == x['data2'].max()].data1.max()]['data1'].nlargest(4))]).reset_index(drop=True)
df3 = df3.sort_values(by=['category', 'data1'], ascending=[True, False]).reset_index(drop=True)

print((df2.data1-df3.data1).max())
print((df2.data2-df3.data2).max())

0.0
0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
n = 200
df['category'] = np.random.choice(('A', 'B'), n)
df['data1'] = np.random.rand(len(df))*100
df['data2'] = np.random.rand(len(df))*100

a = df[df['category'] == 'A']

c = a[a['data2'] == a.data2.max()].data1.max()
a = a[a['data1'] <= c]
a = a.sort_values(by='data1', ascending=False).head(4)

b = df[df['category'] == 'B']
c = b[b['data2'] == b.data2.max()].data1.max()
b = b[b['data1'] <= c]
b = b.sort_values(by='data1', ascending=False).head(4)

df1 = pd.concat([a, b]).sort_values(by=['category', 'data1'], ascending=[True, False]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df1)
  category      data1      data2
0        A  87.560430  99.262452
1        A  85.798945  99.200321
2        A  68.614311  97.796274
3        A  41.641961  95.544980
4        B  69.937691  99.711156
5        B  56.932784  99.227111
6        B  19.903620  94.389186
7        B  12.701288  98.455274
```

Here are first get all `data1` by maximal `data2` per groups, filtered by `<=` and last used `groupby.head`:

```
s = (df.sort_values('data2')
       .drop_duplicates('category', keep='last')
       .set_index('category')['data1'])
df = df[df['data1'] <= df['category'].map(s)]
df1 = (df.sort_values(by=['category', 'data1'], ascending=[True, False])
         .groupby('category')
         .head(4)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
  category      data1      data2
0        A  87.560430  99.262452
1        A  85.798945  99.200321
2        A  68.614311  97.796274
3        A  41.641961  95.544980
4        B  69.937691  99.711156
5        B  56.932784  99.227111
6        B  12.701288  98.455274
7        B  19.903620  94.389186
```